# Tests annotated with DataMongoTest do not terminate the embedded MongoDB at the end

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, flapdoodle-embed-mongo

I noticed experimentally that any integration test class annotated with `@DataMongoTest` does not kill the embedded MongoDB instance it uses. To kill the embedded instance, I have to annotate the test with the annotation `@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)`.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyRepositoryIT.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class MyRepositoryIT{
   // The tests
}
```

The problem highlights when you run long pipelines of tests using Maven. The embedded Mongo instances are killed only when the whole testing process terminates.

Is it correct? Am I making something wrong?

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.10, flapdoodle library, JUnit 4, and version 4.0.2 of MongoDB. I am building the system under Windows.

Comment: I had the same problem. After hours of digging through my test code, I found a place where I did not "close the reactive stream" (sorry, I'm new to this reactive paradigm and not yet well versed with terminology). In my case I had the statement `repository.save(entity).doOnNext { repository.findById(it.id!!) }.subscribe { // do something }` but I forgot to `.dispose()` it in the end. When I added this everything worked correctly again.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, I was not using the reactive driver but the blocking one.